# The parameters for the command "Open" are not currently valid. (Was Not The One Who Made The Script)

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script

So, I'll try to make this as short as I can with providing the needed information, so my sentences might be a bit short. I downloaded a [script to make a custom gamecover 3D.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/1d74g17ayw6cyp3/PC+Box+3D+Converter+v2.zip) I couldn't run the script, because I didn't have photoshop (I had elements, but extendscript couldn't detect it). So I downloaded Photoshop CS2. Whenever I try to run the script I get the error: "The parameters for command 'Open' are not currently valid. I really want to run this script, so if you could help then I would be very much grateful.

NOTE: I came here because the script was made by a guy on NeoGaf, and I wouldn't be able to message him, because apparently NeoGaf is an exclusive site to join. I googled this so much, but to no avail. So, again, if you could help me, I would very much appreciate it.

EDIT: First 30 lines of code:

```
function createFolder( folderObj ){
    if( !folderObj.parent.exists ) createFolder( folderObj.parent );
    if( !folderObj.exists ) folderObj.create();
};

#target photoshop

app.bringToFront();
var tgtwdh=prompt("Please enter the target width in pixels for the output files:",800,"Specify Output Size");
var tgtprc = (tgtwdh / 1759) * 100;

// =======================================================
var idOpn = charIDToTypeID( "Opn " );
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var myPath = File($.fileName).parent.fsName;
desc2.putPath( idnull, new  File( myPath + "/PC_3DBoxTemplate.psd" ) ); // Template file name
executeAction( idOpn, desc2, DialogModes.NO );

createFolder ( new Folder (myPath + "/Export") ); // Create Export Folder if Not Exist

// LOOP THROUGH DIRECTORY
// A hard coded path to a directory 'mac style'
var processFolder = new Folder ( myPath );
// Use folder object get files function with mask 'a reg ex'
var fileList = processFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i);
// Loop through files
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
 // Only process the returned file objects
 // The filter 'should' have missed out any folder objects
```

Comment: "open" probably doesn't work because the file it's trying to access is named differently or it's in a different folder or it simply doesn't exist. Can you find out what line number the script is failing at and copy that relevant code to your question. Or just copy the whole thing

Comment: So, I tried to add the code, but it was too much characters for it, even when I made it a code block. That's why I put the download link, because it has a lot of characters. Though, if you do download it (which I hope you do) it happens at line 18, executeAction( idOpn, desc2, DialogModes.NO );.

Comment: Okay how about pasting the first 30 lines of code.

Comment: I've edited it and pasted the first 30 lines of code. Again, thank you for trying to help. EDIT: I've pasted all of the code at pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/0AYtmPuF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a blind get around but this should start the script:

It's looking for a file called "PC_3DBoxTemplate.psd" so I suggest putting it in in somewhere like c:\temp.
Edit the script accordingly. Change

```
var myPath = File($.fileName).parent.fsName;
desc2.putPath( idnull, new  File( myPath + "\PC_3DBoxTemplate.psd" ) ); // Template file name
```

executeAction( idOpn, desc2, DialogModes.NO );

to

```
var myPath = "C:\\temp";
desc2.putPath( idnull, new  File( myPath + "\\PC_3DBoxTemplate.psd" ) ); // Template file name
```

executeAction( idOpn, desc2, DialogModes.NO );

Not the escape slashes. That should at least open the template file.